# ngrx how to find object by string id and replace in array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

i dispatch object to payload with data ,in NGRX i need to find in array of objects by object id and if its exist replace whole object.

i tried with map , but its just adding the same one to array.

Object example :

```
 datasetId: "9137"
    id: "statedE1123-213-1411" 
    name: "sam" 
    queuePosition: 1 
    status: "QUEUED"
```

```js
export const initialState: State = {
  queueData: []
};

const queueReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,

 on(queueActions.updateQueueData, (state, action) => ({
   ...state,
   queueData: [...state.queueData, action.payload]
  })),

  on(queueActions.updateQueueDataItem, (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    queueData: state.queueData.map(item => (item.id === action.payload.id) ? action.payload : item)
  })),
);
```

```js
export const updateQueueDataItem = createAction(
  '[Queue] Update Queue Data',
  props<{payload: IQueue}>(),
);
```

```js
 this.store.dispatch(updateQueueDataItem({payload: item}));
```

Comment: @Gergő Éles hi, thanks for response, could you show stackblitz if possible or more described answer

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest taking a look into ngrx entity, since it offer a nice solution. Also storing your data in objects would make it easier (exactly what ngrx entity does under the hood), because you could directly reference it by id.

I put together a quick solution:

```
    on(queueActions.updateQueueDataItem, (state, action) => {
     const objectIndex = state.queueData.findIndex(item => (item.id === action.payload.id);

    //Don't do anything
if(objectIndex === -1) return state;

    //Update state immutably

    const filtered =state.queueData.filter((item)=>item.id === action.payload.id);
  
    return{
        ...state,
        queueData: [...filtered,action.payload]
      }
```

}),

Comment: still creating the same objects